# How to share existing char * with an other process?

Tags: c, memory, posix, share

I'm trying to share some memory with an other forked+execed process using `shmget` and `shmat`:

```
char test[]="test";
int shID;
char *shptr;
key_t shkey = 2404;

shID = shmget(shkey, sizeof(char)*(strlen(test)+1), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (shID >= 0) {
    shptr = shmat(shID, 0, 0);
    if (shptr==(char *)-1) {
        perror("shmat");
    } else {
        memcpy(shptr, &test, strlen(test)+1);
        ....
        //forking and execing
        ....
        shmdt(shptr);
    }
} else {
    perror("shmget");
}
```

This works fine.

The thing is that  `test[]` is going to be a huge `char*`. So I liked easy to share `text[]` instead of copying it.Is there any better way to handle this?

Comment: What is test[] storing? Can you not get the content of test[] once you have obtained shptr? Then you could completely get rid of test[].

Comment: I was thinking about that too. test[] gets its content from some parts of a file. I can't know how tall test[] will be, until I test is loaded.

Comment: Can you read the size of the file and allocate enough memory to hold the whole file? It is not space-optimal since you seem to want to read just part of this file but it would do what you want.

Comment: Yes I can do that. At the moment I'm working on a work around: I write the needed size directly in the file.

Answer (score 0):

if you can read file size or exact memory which you want to read from file and location than you can use mmap to map that part of file to memory.